# JPA - Problemas con persist de @ManyToOne

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa, java-8

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion en la que se requiere que se guarden datos de facultades y carreras y he creado las siguientes entities:

> Facultad

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "uc_facultades", schema = "uc")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Facultades_id_seq", sequenceName = "uc.uc_facultades_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Facultad implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Facultades_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 70)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "estado", columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private Boolean estado;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="facultad", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Carrera> carreras;

//Getters y Setters

 public void addCarrera(Carrera carrera){
        carreras.add(carrera);
        if(carrera.getFacultad() != this){
            carrera.setFacultad(this);
        }
    }
}
```

> Carrera

```
@Entity
@Table(name="uc_carreras", schema="uc")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Carreras_id_seq", sequenceName = "uc.uc_carreras_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Carrera implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Carreras_id_seq")
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max=80)
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="estado", columnDefinition="boolean default true")
    private boolean estado = true;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Facultad.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="idfacultad", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false, insertable = false)
    private Facultad facultad;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Pensum.class)
    @JoinTable(name="uc.uc_pensum_carrera", 
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idcarrera", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false), 
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idpensum", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false))
    @OrderBy(value = "año DESC")
    private List<Pensum> pensums;

//Getters y Setters
}
```

Este codigo es con el que registro una nueva carrera:

```
@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) 
public void guardarCarrera(CarrerasDTO carreraDTO) {
        LOG.info("[CarrerasService][guardarCarrera]");
        try {
            Facultad facultad = em.find(Facultad.class, carreraDTO.getFacultad().getId());//Se extrae la entity
            Carrera carrera = new Carrera();
            carrera.setNombre(carreraDTO.getNombre());
            carrera.setFacultad(facultad);    
            carrera.setEstado(Boolean.TRUE);
            carreraDTO.getPensums().stream().forEach(pensum -> {
                carrera.addPensum(pensum); 
            });
            em.persist(carrera);   
            em.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "[CarrerasService][guardarCarrera] Excepcion -> {0}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Si inteto persistir con CascadeType.PERSIST o CascadeTYpe.ALLme lanza la siguiente excepcion:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «pk_facultad»
```

Si utilizo el CascadeType.MERGE me lanza la siguiente excepcion:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: el valor null para la columna «idfacultad» viola la restricción not null
```

Llevo varios dias investigando y corrigiendo las entities y el metodo pero nada funciona espero me puedan ayudar.

NOTA: Para el desarrollo de esto estoy usando:

- Java EE 7 (Aplicacion Web)
- JPA 2.1 con EclipseLink
- EJB Lite 3.2

Comment: Probaste eliminando la cascada para la relacion facultad en la entidad carrera? No tiene mucho sentido que la creación de una carrera cree una facultad

Comment: Me lanza la excepcion que el campo idfacultad esta nulo:

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: el valor null para la columna «idfacultad» viola la restricción not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En carrera, tienes:

```
@JoinColumn(name="idfacultad", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false, insertable = false)
private Facultad facultad;
```

La documentación para `@JoinColumn` especifica:

> insertable
>   public abstract boolean insertable (Optional)
>   Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provider.

Que es justamente lo que está ocurriendo, en insert la columna si debería ir incluida.

Comment: Buena respuesta, aquí hay más información (en inglés): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805584/please-explain-about-insertable-false-updatable-false

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora tengo un problema con la relacion muchos a muchos entre carrera y pensum pero creo que publicare otra pregunta para ello